# Linked list implementation along with unit test

Tags: c#, beginner, linked-list, unit-testing

I've already made all the changes suggested here. Here is the link for round 2: [Linked list implementation along with unit test [Round 2]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216503/linked-list-implementation-along-with-unit-test-round-2)

I want to see how other people think of my code, so here it goes. This is my first time writing a unit test. I'm wondering if there needs to be more tests for the LinkedList class and also if I'm writing them correctly.

I've made the Node class public so I can use it for a binary tree implementation later.

```
namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures
{
    public class Node<T>
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
        public Node<T> Previous { get; set; }

        public Node() { }

        public Node(T t)
        {
            Data = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures
{
    public class LinkedList<T>
    {
        public Node<T> Head { get; private set; }
        public Node<T> Tail { get; private set; }

        public LinkedList(Node<T> node)
        {
            Head = node;
            Tail = node;
        }

        public void AddToFirst(Node<T> toAdd)
        {
            toAdd.Next = Head;
            Head = toAdd;
        }

        public void AddToLast(Node<T> toAdd)
        {
            Tail.Next = toAdd;
            Tail = toAdd;
        }

        public void RemoveFirst()
        {
            Head = Head.Next;
        }

        public void RemoveLast()
        {
            var pointer = Head;
            while (pointer.Next != Tail)
            {
                pointer = pointer.Next;
            }
            // pointer is now before Tail
            Tail = pointer;
            Tail.Next = null;
        }

        public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var pointer = Head;
            while (pointer != null)
            {
                yield return pointer;
                pointer = pointer.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
using System;
using Xunit;

using DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures.Tests
{
    public class LinkedListTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void AddToFirst_Node_Should_Become_Head()
        {
            // Arrange
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(new Node<int>(45));

            // Act
            var nodeToAdd = new Node<int>(67);
            myLinkedList.AddToFirst(nodeToAdd);

            // Assert
            var theNode = GetNodeFromList<int>(myLinkedList, nodeToAdd);
            Assert.Equal(nodeToAdd, theNode);
            Assert.Equal(45, theNode.Next.Data);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void AddToLast_Node_Should_Become_Tail()
        {
            // Arrange
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(new Node<int>(35));

            // Act
            var nodeToAdd = new Node<int>(14);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(nodeToAdd);

            // Assert
            var theNode = GetNodeFromList<int>(myLinkedList, nodeToAdd);
            Assert.Equal(nodeToAdd, theNode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void RemoveFirst_Next_Node_Should_Be_Head()
        {
            // Arrange
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(new Node<int>(777));

            var node1 = new Node<int>(1);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node1);

            var node2 = new Node<int>(2);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node2);

            var node3 = new Node<int>(3);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node3);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.RemoveFirst();

            // Assert
            var theNode = GetNodeFromList<int>(myLinkedList, node1);
            Assert.Equal(node1, myLinkedList.Head);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void RemoveLast_Next_Node_Should_Be_Tail()
        {
            // Arrange
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(new Node<int>(777));

            var node1 = new Node<int>(1);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node1);

            var node2 = new Node<int>(2);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node2);

            var node3 = new Node<int>(3);
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(node3);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.RemoveLast();

            // Assert
            var theNode = GetNodeFromList<int>(myLinkedList, node2);
            Assert.Equal(node2, myLinkedList.Tail);
        }

        public static Node<T> GetNodeFromList<T>(LinkedList<T> someLinkedList, Node<T> someNode) where T : struct
        {
            using (var itr = someLinkedList.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (itr.Current != someNode)
                {
                    itr.MoveNext();
                }
                return itr.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Presentation

````
using System;
using System.Collections;

using DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.Presentation.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunNode();
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            RunLinkedList();
        }

        static void RunNode()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Running the Node class");
            System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------");
            var myNode = new Node<int>(32);
            System.Console.WriteLine(myNode.Data);
        }

        static void RunLinkedList()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Running the LinkedList class");
            System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(new Node<int>(99));
            myLinkedList.AddToFirst(new Node<int>(56));
            myLinkedList.AddToFirst(new Node<int>(23));
            myLinkedList.AddToFirst(new Node<int>(33));
            myLinkedList.AddToLast(new Node<int>(8888));
            myLinkedList.RemoveLast();
            myLinkedList.RemoveFirst();
            System.Console.WriteLine("HEAD = " + myLinkedList.Head.Data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("TAIL = " + myLinkedList.Tail.Data);

            using (var linkedListEnumerator = myLinkedList.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (linkedListEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(linkedListEnumerator.Current.Data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've made the Node class public so I can use it for a binary tree implementation later

I don't think you can use this `Node` type as a node in a binary tree, because nodes in binary trees typically has references to other nodes like `Parent`, `Left` and `Right`. So IMO keep this `Node` class as a dedicated node type for this linked list:

```
  public class LinkedList<T>
  {
    class Node
    {
      public T Data { get; }
      public Node Next { get; set; }
      public Node Previous { get; set; }

      public Node(T data)
      {
        Data = data;
      }
    }
```

In this way you can skip the type parameter on the `Node` class. As shown above I've also made the `Node` class immutable for the `Data` property and hence no default constructor. It's easier to maintain, if you know that there is a one-to-one relationship between a data object and a `Node`.

---

> ```
> public Node<T> Head { get; private set; }
> public Node<T> Tail { get; private set; }
> ```

It's fine to have a public `Head` and `Tail` property, but they should be of type `T` and not `Node`. The client should be agnostic about the inner implementation of your list and only "communicate" objects of type `T` with it:

```
public T Head => _headNode.Data; // TODO check for null
public T Tail => _tailNode.Data; // TODO check for null
```

This will require that you have private nodes for head and tail as illustrated above.

---

> ```
> public LinkedList(Node<T> node)
> {
>   Head = node;
>   Tail = node;
> }
> ```

Having a one and only constructor that takes a node (or item) is not a good idea, because you often want to instantiate an empty list and provide it as argument to a method or something like that. So your list should have a default constructor with no arguments:

```
public LinkedList()
{
}
```

You could also consider to have a constructor with a vector of items:

```
public LinkedList(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  foreach (var item in items)
  {
    AddTail(item);
  }
}
```

---

> ```
> public void AddToFirst(Node toAdd) {...}
>     public void AddToLast(Node toAdd) {...}
> ```

You would typically call these methods `AddHead` and `AddTail`:

```
public void AddHead(T item) {...}
public void AddTail(T item) {...}
```

as you would call `RemoveFirst()` `RemoveHead()`...

---

> ```
> public void AddToFirst(Node<T> toAdd)
> {
>   toAdd.Next = Head;
>   Head = toAdd;
> }
>
> public void AddToLast(Node<T> toAdd)
> {
>   Tail.Next = toAdd; //OBS: This will fail if Tail is null!
>   Tail = toAdd;
> }
> ```

Your `Node<T>` class has a `Previous` property, why don't you use that (doubly linked list)?

---

> ```
> public void RemoveFirst()
> {
>   Head = Head.Next;
> }
> ```

This will fail, if `Head` is `null`.

---

> ```
> public void RemoveLast()
> {
>   var pointer = Head;
>   while (pointer.Next != Tail)
>   {
>     pointer = pointer.Next;
>   }
>   // pointer is now before Tail
>   Tail = pointer;
>   Tail.Next = null;
> }
> ```

Why iterate through the entire list, when you have a reference to the last node in `Tail`?:

```
public void RemoveLast()
{
  if (Tail != null)
  {
    Tail = Tail.Previous;
    Tail.Next = null;
  }
}
```

You could consider to return the `Data` value from the removed nodes.

```
public T RemoveLast() {...}
```

---

> ```
> public IEnumerator<Node<T>> GetEnumerator()
> {
>   var pointer = Head;
>   while (pointer != null)
>   {
>     yield return pointer;
>     pointer = pointer.Next;
>   }
> }
> ```

It's fine to provide an enumerator. But it would be better to implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface instead - where T is the `T` from your list - not `Node<T>`.

If you do that, instead of this

> ```
>   using (var linkedListEnumerator = myLinkedList.GetEnumerator())
>   {
>     while (linkedListEnumerator.MoveNext())
>     {
>       Console.WriteLine(linkedListEnumerator.Current.Data);
>     }
>   }
> ```

you would be able to do

```
  foreach (var item in myLinkedList)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
```

And besides that, by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll be able to use LINQ extensions on the list. (see also VisualMelons comment).

---

Consider to implement this:

```
public bool Remove(T item)
{
  // TODO: implement this
  return <wasRemoved>;
}
```

---

You could try to implement the above and make a new post with an updated version with unit tests and we could then review that... :-)

Your use case should look as something like:

```
void RunLinkedList()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Running the LinkedList class");
  Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
  var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
  myLinkedList.AddHead(99);
  myLinkedList.AddHead(56);
  myLinkedList.AddHead(23);
  myLinkedList.AddHead(33);
  myLinkedList.AddTail(8888);
  myLinkedList.RemoveTail();
  myLinkedList.RemoveHead();
  Console.WriteLine("HEAD = " + myLinkedList.Head);
  Console.WriteLine("TAIL = " + myLinkedList.Tail);

  foreach (var item in myLinkedList)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }

}
```

Comment: With your suggestion, `public T RemoveLast() {...}`, doesn't it violate 
Command-Query Separation? RemoveLast() modifies state. Is It okay to break the rule sometimes?

Comment: +1; sadly (IMO) you can already use `foreach` on the OP's class, but properly implementing `IEnumerable<T>` will facilitate much more.

Comment: @VisualMelon: You're right. I know you can, but what I intended to show was that the Enumerator enumerates the `T`'s and not the `Node<T>`s. By implementing IEnumerable<T> you'll be able to use the standard Linq extensions etc.

Comment: @feature_creep: IMO CQS is about not changing the object (the list) when querying it. Here I do the opposite: changing the object and provide the "change" to the client - it's not a query. It's a little different.