# Linked list implementation along with unit test - Round 2

Tags: c#, beginner, linked-list, unit-testing

Here is the link to the next round of code review: [Linked list implementation along with unit test [Round 3]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216758/linked-list-implementation-along-with-unit-test-round-3)

Here's the link to the previous code review:
[Linked list implementation along with unit test](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216453/linked-list-implementation-along-with-unit-test)

Implementation

```
/*************************************************************************************************************
 *
 *  Special Thanks to Henrik Hansen for the awesome code review!
 *  Url: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216453/linked-list-implementation-along-with-unit-test
 *
 *************************************************************************************************************/

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures
{
    public class LinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        class Node
        {
            public T Data { get; }
            public Node Next { get; set; }
            public Node Previous { get; set; }

            public Node(T data)
            {
                Data = data;
            }
        }

        private Node _head, _tail;
        public T Head => _head == null ? throw new ArgumentNullException("Head is null") : _head.Data;
        public T Tail => _tail == null ? throw new ArgumentNullException("Tail is null") : _tail.Data;

        public LinkedList() { }

        public LinkedList(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                AddTail(item);
            }
        }

        public void AddHead(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("AddHead: An item you are trying to add is not initialized!");

            if (_head == null && _tail == null)
            {
                _head = new Node(item);
                _tail = _head;
            }
            else
            {
                _head.Previous = new Node(item);
                var temp = _head;
                _head = _head.Previous;
                _head.Next = temp;
            }
        }

        public void AddTail(T item)
        {
            if (item == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("AddTail: An item you are trying to add is not initialized!");

            if (_tail == null && _head == null)
            {
                _tail = new Node(item);
                _head = _tail;
            }
            else
            {
                _tail.Next = new Node(item);
                var temp = _tail;
                _tail = _tail.Next;
                _tail.Previous = temp;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveHead()
        {
            if (_head == null) return;
            else
            {
                _head = _head.Next;
                if (_head == null) return;
                _head.Previous = null;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveTail()
        {
            if (_tail == null) return;
            else
            {
                _tail = _tail.Previous;
                if (_tail == null) return;
                _tail.Next = null;
            } 
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            var pointer = _head;
            while (pointer.Data.Equals(item) == false)
            {
                if (pointer.Next == null)
                    return false;
                pointer = pointer.Next;
            }

            if (pointer.Previous == null)
            {
                // It is the Head
                pointer.Next.Previous = null;
                return true;
            }
            if (pointer.Next == null)
            {
                // It is the Tail
                pointer.Previous.Next = null;
                return true;
            }
            pointer.Previous.Next = null;
            pointer.Next.Previous = null;
            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var pointer = _head;
            while (pointer != null)
            {
                yield return pointer.Data;
                pointer = pointer.Next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
using System;
using Xunit;

using DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures.Tests
{
    public class LinkedListTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void AddHead_Node_Should_Become_Head()
        {
            // Arrange
            int[] myNums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(myNums);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.AddHead(45);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(45, myLinkedList.Head);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void AddTail_Node_Should_Become_Tail()
        {
            // Arrange
            int[] myNums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(myNums);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.AddTail(7777);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(7777, myLinkedList.Tail);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void RemoveHead_Next_Node_Should_Be_Head()
        {
            // Arrange
            int[] myNums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(myNums);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.RemoveHead();

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(2, myLinkedList.Head);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void RemoveTail_Next_Node_Should_Be_Tail()
        {
            // Arrange
            int[] myNums = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>(myNums);

            // Act
            myLinkedList.RemoveTail();

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(4, myLinkedList.Tail);
        }
    }
}
```

Presentation

````
using System;
using System.Collections;

using DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.Presentation.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunLinkedList();
        }

        static void RunLinkedList()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Running the LinkedList class");
            System.Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");
            var myLinkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
            myLinkedList.AddHead(54);
            myLinkedList.AddHead(44);
            myLinkedList.AddHead(96);
            myLinkedList.AddTail(300);
            myLinkedList.AddTail(900);
            myLinkedList.AddTail(77);
            myLinkedList.Remove(900);

            System.Console.WriteLine("HEAD = " + myLinkedList.Head);
            System.Console.WriteLine("TAIL = " + myLinkedList.Tail);

            foreach (var item in myLinkedList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: I have found an error where it prints the wrong tail. I will be fixing this. This means I must be missing some tests.

Comment: I find it difficult to add valuable tests like `public void Head_Should_Only_Have_Previous_Equal_NULL()` and `public void Tail_Should_Only_Have_Next_Equal_NULL()` when my `_head` and `_tail` member variables are set to private.

Answer (score 4):

- `Remove...` family methods fail with an exception if from the list is of size 1. `pointer.Previous == null` does not mean that `pointer.Next` is not.
- It is quite important to convey a success/failure of the removal to the caller. `Remove` should return at least a boolean.
- I am not sure why do you disallow a `Node` having `null` data. In any case, if you want to enforce it, do it in a `Node` constructor, rather than in insertion methods.
- `AddHead` should be streamlined. After all, the `new Node` is created in both branches, and becomes `head` no matter what. Lift the common functionality out:

  ```
  public void AddHead(T item)
  {
      var node = new Node(item);
      node.Next = _head;

      if (_head == null && _tail == null)
      {
          _tail = node;
      }
      else
      {
          _head.Previous = node;
      }
      _head = node;
  }
  ```

  Ditto for `AddTail`.
- A `while (pointer.Data.Equals(item) == false)` loop deserves to become a `Find` method.

Answer (score 3):

Much better.

I have the following to add to vnp's answer:

> ```
> public T Head => _head == null ? throw new ArgumentNullException("Head is null") : _head.Data;
> public T Tail => _tail == null ? throw new ArgumentNullException("Tail is null") : _tail.Data;
> ```

Instead of `ArgumentNullException` it's better to use `NullReferenceException` because there is no argument.

---

Instead of iterating this way:

> ```
>   while (pointer.Data.Equals(item) == false)
>   {
>     if (pointer.Next == null)
>       return false;
>     pointer = pointer.Next;
>   }
> ```

I find it more intuitive to do:

```
  Node node = _head;
  while (node != null)
  {
    if (item.Equals(node.Data))
    {
      break;
    }

    node = node.Next;
  }

  if (node == null) return false;
```

---

Instead of this:

> ```
>   if (pointer.Previous == null)
>   {
>     // It is the Head
>     pointer.Next.Previous = null;
>     return true;
>   }
> ```

consider reuse `RemoveHead()`:

```
  if (node == _head)
  {
    RemoveHead();
    return true;
  }
```

That will be more DRY. And you can do the same for the tail.

---

You could consider to implement:

```
public bool IsEmpty { get; }
public int Count { get; }
```

---

You tests seems OK to me. You're missing one for `Remove(T value)`.

About "Head_Should_Only_Have_Previous_Equal_NULL": unit tests are about testing the public interface of an object, so checking for `_head.Previous == null` should be tested indirectly through testing the public interface. In fact you'd have to test for it every time you make a change to the list. An indirect test could be trying to remove the head or tail from an empty list. If that doesn't fail, it may indicate that something is wrong with the handling of `Node.Previous`. In your case, you'll then have to throw or return false from `RemoveHead()` to find out...